# Does the Chronos GX have a count up setting?

Tags: chess-clocks

I've had the Chronos GX for a while now. However, I don't use it much anymore because I need a count up setting. In other words, I'd like it to start at 0 and have it count up as time is spent.

The regular Chronos has the `UP-1` and `UP-2` settings. The GX seems to lack those. Or am I missing something?

[The GX user manual](http://www.metrowestchess.org/community/Knowledge/Digital_Clocks/Clock_Chronos/Chronos_GX_Digital_Game_CLock/Chronos_GX_Manual.pdf) doesn’t give me much hope.

Comment: I spent over $100 on this clock and I'd rather not spend another $100 on the regular one.

Comment: Yeah, and my old Chronos II can't handle multiple time controls with delay and move counter while also showing the number of delay seconds remaining... It would probably be better if these clocks were fully programmable instead of having so many presets. Chronos clocks were the best back in the day but now it seems that there are many alternatives that are also much cheaper.

Comment: Why would you want to count up?

Comment: @edwinaoliver, it is a non-standard use case, but at the time I wanted a way to keep track of time without putting a limit on how much time one can use. I've long since abandoned this idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the Chronus GX clock does not have a count up mode.

While the normal one does, as you have mentioned, it seems that the GX doesn’t. I found this [video](https://youtu.be/LHMc6yM3yRM) on how to set up a count on the normal one. It cites pages 35-36 of the manual on how to do this. As expected, the [online PDF of the manual](http://www.chesspraga.cz/download/manualy/ChronosManual.pdf) corresponds to the video’s given information.

My conclusion is that if the GX manual does not contain information on how to do it, then it cannot do it. Further evidence of this from this [video](https://youtu.be/8gKS70XnQeg) on how to use GX clock. As far as I can tell, it has no mention of a count up setting.

So unfortunately the Chronus GX Clock has no count up setting as far as I can tell.